# Постоянное обновление label в Glade

Tags: c++, linux, c

Как постоянно обновлять *label*? В интернете куча статей о изменение *label* с помощью кнопки, но мне нужно в цикле выводить информацию.
После gtk_main() нет смысла как я понял что либо(gtk_label_set_label();gtk_label_set_text();), значит надо другим способом, в *Google* ничего не нашел.

Comment: Что за Label? В чем? Тут не телепаты, не знают, в какой программе работаете, что делаете. Подробнее.

Comment: Программа Glade. Создаем простенькую программку: окно, в него label. Привязываемся через с++ к namefile.glade. Всё хорошо, показывает окно с "HelloWorld", но нигде не нашел обновление существующего label, например "HelloWorld1", "HelloWorld2" ..

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka графический редактор для создания графических интерфейсов на основе GTK+

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал изменять label в другом потоке, всё работает.